# PowerPoint 2010 - VBA - Use Ribbon Button Inside of a Userform

Tags: vba, ribbon, color-picker, powerpoint-2010

Is it possible to take a pre-existing button from the ribbon, Shape Fill from the Shape Styles category for example, and display it in a VBA userform?

My add-in manages a large number of shapes, and I would like to allow the user to style those shapes based on the category that they are in in the add-in.

I have read that a color dialog does not exist for us to use in VBA, so I'm trying to think of a way to work around that. Recreating all of the fill, outline, and effects menus seems like too much, there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

No, built-in ribbon controls can be used on the ribbon only. As a workaround you may consider using any ActiveX custom controls on your form.

Also you may consider creating a custom UI on the ribbon. In that case you will be able to add built-in ribbon controls to your own tab by specifying its idMso value. The full list of control IDs can be found in the following documents:

- [Office 2010 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)
- [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)
- [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)